# How to disable swipe in VTabs component in Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuetifyjs3, vuetify-tabs

I am using `<v-tabs>` component with a couple of tabs and want to disable the swipe functionality.

In Vuetify 2 this was done using the `touchless` prop on `<v-tabs-items>` but this option does not exist in Vuetify 3 as V3 no longer uses the `<v-tabs-items>` wrapper.

Is there another way I can disable this for the tabs or even the entire card or the window containing the tabs?

My code is as follows:

```
<v-card>
  <v-tabs v-model="twoTabs">
    <v-tab value="tab1">Tab One</v-tab>
    <v-tab value="tab2">Tab Two</v-tab>
  </v-tabs>
  <v-window v-model="twoTabs">
    <v-window-item value="tab1">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Tab One Text</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-window-item>
    <v-window-item value="tab2">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Tab Two Text</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-window-item>
  </v-window>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add prop `disabled` on v-window.
See below example:

```
<v-window disabled v-model="twoTabs">
   ...
</v-window>
```

More info see the doc [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-window/#props-disabled).

Comment: Yes, this seems like the more elegant solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<v-window>` provides as touch prop (see [API doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-window/#props-touch)) that takes a callback function. You can return false and the behavior will be the same as touchless, disabling the swipe action:

```
...
<v-window v-model="twoTabs" :touch="touchless()">
...
methods: {
  touchless() {
      return false;
  }
},
```